# Seek_END seeking backwards

Tags: c, struct, scanf, fseek

So I stored a struct to a sequential file in this format `"%d %s %s %f"` what I am wondering is , if I am seeking the last record from a file , and I use `fseek(*val,offset*-1,Seek_end` when i use `fscanf` would it read backwards? So I would have to read `"%f %s %s %d"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't cause subsequent reads to go backwards, reads *always* go forwards.

All it does is sets the file pointer to that distance from the end of file. So, if you have a file containing the English letters and you seek with `-5` and `SEEK_END`, the next reads will give you `vwxyz` *in that order.*

Comment: Note that common descriptions of `fseek` bear a warning on using it with text files, such as: "Text files: Either zero, or a value returned by *ftell*." (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)